# What is the best way to do BULK INSERT using Java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, insert, bulk

I'm trying to make an app that can save a lot of structured objects in the database.
Now I am using Spring Data JPA (with hibernate + MySQL (MyIsam tables + foreign keys)) 
Write code for data services is easy and pleasant using Spring Data repositories but performance is too slow.

For example, I tried to insert 100 records in one table and it takes for a 8,5 sec.

I've try to do the same insert operations straight in MySQL cmd (using hardcoded "insert strings" in a procedure) and it shows me time - 0,85 sec. Even such a result for me is too slow, but this is the problem of MySQL

Reading the forum I have found the [post](http://forum.springsource.org/showth...CrudRepository) which says that Spring Data JPA can't do the bulk insert properly.

How can I make my app more faster? I want to use bulk INSERT operations with size like a 1000 or more.

The situation is complicated by the fact that I can't store my object to db in one bulk (despite the size of bulk)

To make it clearer:

> ```
> The objectGame contains list of objectRound
> The objectGame also contains list of objectGamePlayer
> The objectRound contains list of objectRoundCard
> The objectGamePlayer contains list of objectPlayerCard
> The objectGamePlayer also contains list of objectPlayerBet
> ```

Of course, to insert an objectGame it needs to make several steps:
Insert bulk of objectGame and get their Ids
Having objectGame's Ids insert bulk of objectRound and get their Ids 
... and so on

Which way is more appropriate for me?

Using Spring Data JPA, jdbc, hibernate, myBatis? Or another way ?

Comment: You have your answer already - MySQL and INSERT strings.  You'll only do it once.  Get a shovel, INSERT the records, and move on.

Comment: as duffymo has pointed out, direct db interacetion will always be quicker.  have you considered using Spring Batch?

Comment: perhaps, spring batch will help me. I'm not too familiar with its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that Spring Data JPA by default does not do bulk insert in an efficient way. We faced this issue when we wanted to write more than 25000 objects in bulk to a table and we had 8 such tables to write. Here is how we did it.

By default Spring Data JPA would fetch the object into EntityManager's cache and then compare and decide whether to call persist or merge. I bypassed that logic, since i knew based on version whether i want to persist or merge. The trick is determining based on `if (entity.getVersion() == 0) {`

```
public List<T> update(Collection<T> entities) {
        List<T> ret =  new ArrayList<>();
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        for (T entity : entities) {
            if (entity.getVersion() == 0) {
                em.persist(entity);
                ret.add(entity);
            } else {
                ret.add(em.merge(entity));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

You would need Handle to the EntityManager, which you can obtain by Creating your own implementation of JPA Repository simply extending SimpleJpaRepository class.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;

public class MyJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        
        // Keep the EntityManager around to used from the newly introduced methods.
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

And on your SpringConfig of the application add the following annoation to instantiate your repo implementation instead of the default  SimpleJpaRepository using `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "..." , repositoryBaseClass = MyJpaRepositoryImpl.class)`

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "au.com.xyz.infrastructure.repositories" , repositoryBaseClass = MyJpaRepositoryImpl.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"au.com.xyz.infrastructure.repositories.plugin", "au.com.xyz.infrastructure.repositories.external", ...})

public class InfrastructureSpringConfig {
```